# Not able to implement common header.php for my website

Tags: php, html

I am trying a put a common header file across all my pages on the website. I am just doing it for one page currently.

I am using a class "current" to mark a given page as the current page. I am not able to do this using the below html. The header shows 'class="current" href="contact.php" > Contact Us' instead of just "Contact Us". Running the code would give you a better idea.

Seems to be a simple issue but somehow am not able to fix this. Kindly help.

```
<?php               
$pagename=strtolower(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
?>    
    <div id="header">
        <div id="site_title">

        </div>  <!-- end of site_title -->
    </div><!-- end of header -->

    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.php" class="current">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="getstarted.php">Getting Started</a></li>
            <li><a href="account.php">My Account</a></li>
            <li class="current"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a <? if ($pagename=='contact.php') {?> class="current" <? } ?> href="contact.php" >Contact Us</a></li>


        </ul> 
    </div> <!-- end of menu -->

    <div id="middle">
        <h1>Welcome to my site</h1>
        <p></p> 
    </div> <!-- end middle-->
```

----------------updated---------------------------

I am not sure what might be the reason for this.. The second line works for me and the first does not.. Would appreciate if anyone tells me why is this strange behaviour

```
<li <? if ($pagename=='about.php') {?> class="current" <? } ?>><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
<li <?php if ($pagename=='contact.php') {?> class="current" <?php } ?>><a href="contact.php" >Contact Us</a></li>
```

Comment: I just copied your code, and it's working here? http://justcandan.com/SO/contact.php

Comment: thanks guys..please see the updated part of the question

Comment: This is because the short tag option is not enabled in php.ini

Comment: <? ?> are short_tags and need to be enabled in your php.ini settings if you want to use them.

Answer (score 0):

Is the value in $pagename == "contact.php"?

Julian

Answer (score -1):

Your code About us has class="current". This is not in any condition like the "Contact US" page. So you can't see difference.

```
<li class="current"><a href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
```

Comment: That's not the issue, he has raw HTML rendering out.

Comment: I understand this. I have tried the code and it worked fine. So I thought he might not be able to distinguish it.